# Insert series values into a separate pandas column where values are null

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['foo','Bar','Foo','jim','john','mary','jim'],
                   'code1':[np.nan,np.nan,'432',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'563']})

df1

    name    code1
0   foo     NaN
1   Bar     NaN
2   Foo     432
3   jim     NaN
4   john    NaN
5   mary    NaN
6   jim     563


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'xyz':['this','column','doesnt','matter'],
                   'code2':['123','345','456','234']})

df2

    xyz      code2
0   this     123
1   column   345
2   doesnt  456
3   matter   234
```

There are missing values in the `code1` column in df1. I don't really need any to match up, I just want to add some extra codes into this column.

So I have df2, with a `code2` column. I want to take those four codes, and add them into four cells in df1.

My expected output is this:

```
df3

    name    code
0   foo     123 # new code
1   Bar     345 # new code
2   Foo     432 # code unchanged
3   jim     456 # new code 
4   john    234 # new code
5   mary    NaN # not important
6   jim     563 # code unchanged
```

What have I tried so far?

I've saved the codes from df2

```
codes = df2['code2']

codes

0    123
1    345
2    456
3    234
Name: code, dtype: object
```

I then filtered df1 to have null codes only as I don't want to replace codes that are present, and since I only have four new codes to insert, I got the first four rows of df1  and assigned the new codes to them:

```
mask = df1['code1'].isnull()

df1['code1'][mask][:4] = codes
```

However nothing happened to df1. Still has nans.

Some other things I tried, getting the values, but didn't work either:

```
df1['code1'][mask][:4].values = codes.values
```

And then I'm just running out of ideas here. Doesn't work

```
df1['code1'][mask][list(range(4))] = codes.values
```

Comment: You have two Bar in df2, which one you want the df1 updated ?

Comment: Your `df1` and `df1` aren't the same.

Comment: Sorry, there's something wrong with stack overflow this eve it seems. People here are seeing a different version of df1 and df2 than I am. edit: I just saw that. Edited now.

Comment: So you want to fill the first 4 `NaNs` with the 4 values from your other data frame, regardless of the value of `'name'`?

Comment: Exactly CJR. I could just do this in excel by pasting the codes from `df2` into any blank cells in `df1['code']`. but just wanted to try it in pandas. i've edited the data a bit to show that I don't care about the xyz col in df2. I just have it in there because I have extra random cols in the real dataset. so whatever I try with the dummy data has to kind of match the real data.

Comment: Since you don't care about either `df1.name` or `df2.xyz` let alone matching either of them, it would be less confusing to simply show `df1.code1` and `df2.code2`. Keep your example as simple as needs be. (You want to match your dfs by the indices of NaN/non-NaN values respectively)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
s = df1.loc[df1.code1.isnull(),'code1']
# Filter the df1 first...
s.iloc[:len(df2)] = df2.code2.values
# Assign value to NaNs, regardless of index...
df1.loc[df1.code1.isnull(), 'code1'] = s

# Assign the result back 
df1
   name code1
0   foo   123
1   Bar   345
2   Foo   432
3   jim   456
4  john   234
5  mary   NaN
6   jim   563
```

Comment: It was very difficult to explain, but you got it. I basically wanted to copy the codes from `df2` into any blank cells in `df1['code1']`. could have done it in excel in 2 seconds but was stubborn. thanks again.

Comment: Just one clarification, why did you use `.iloc` in the second line? If you use `.loc` it works also. Any particular reason?

Comment: @SCool .iloc will slice by position , .loc is slice by the index , so that is different

Answer (score 2):

Same thing as the other answer, just a bit different on implementation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

na_num = pd.isna(df1['code1']).sum()
replacer = df2['code2'].tolist() + max(na_num - len(df2), 0) * [np.nan]
df1.loc[pd.isna(df1['code1']), 'code1'] = replacer[:na_num]
```

Comment: How are you joining `df1` and `df2` on `'name'` when only `df1` has `'name'`?

Comment: It's also possible that I don't actually understand what logic you want to use.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think there might be a bug with stack overflow. You're using a dataframe that's not in my question! The df is in some code in my notebook, that I copied over and edited before posting. It looks like it doesn't display the edits I make before posting (but it does for me)

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. Thanks for your patience. For readability, i will go with WeNYoBen's answer. Your one is a bit too complex for me :) haven't gotten to grips with numpy just yet

Comment: His answer is better than mine. IMO.